# Unity 2018 : GUI.DrawTexture doesn't draw anything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a point and click game and I want to print an image when the player click in definded zones. For now the zones are working (when I click on the table the game says "Table") but the method `GUI.DrawTexture()` isn't drawing anything. I've check the cass, change the rect values but nothing works.

Here's the code:

```
public Texture2D[] ImagesFixes;
private bool afficher;
private string text;
private Texture2D myTexture;

void OnGUI () {

    afficher = false;
    text = Tap(); //Tap is a fonction that returns the associate text of the clicked zone

    if (text == "Table") {

    //  Debug.Log (text);
        afficher = true;

        if (afficher) {

            myTexture = ImagesFixes [0];

            //Debug.Log ("je suis là");

            GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (10, 10, 60, 60), myTexture, ScaleMode.ScaleToFit, false, 10.0f);

        }
    }

    if (text == "Boite") {

        afficher = true;

        if (afficher) {

            GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (10, 10, 60, 60), ImagesFixes[1], ScaleMode.ScaleToFit, true, 10.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a solution please help me, I'm going mad... =)

Comment: Your code works for me. But are you sure `Tap()` function returns `Table` or `Boite` correctly?

Comment: GUI is generally repreciated from the player (its stays in the editor for now), have you considered using the UGui system instead?

Comment: Ehsan : Yes I've put Debug messages pretty everywhere befor asking! =)

Comment: Zambari : No when I've read the doc of unity I didn't see UGui... I'll look at it and try it thanks!

Comment: But Ehsan, You say it works for you? That means that the problem is somewhere else... Ok it make me think differant thanks for help, if I find a solution I'll answer myself for other users! =)